# My react site shows up blank on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, netlify

I deployed my react site with netlify here https://clusterfy.netlify.app/ I tried it on my computer and it works, but on my phone it doesn’t. So far I’ve tried to change the basename of Browser router to “/React”. added a homepage element in package.json that points to the root of the site. I got rid of `%PUBLIC%` and replaced it with the link to my site. Here’s the repo for it https://github.com/andrewpaige1/clusterfy-front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by pushing one component at a time. I ended up figuring out it was an issue with the react-sketch library or jsdom. Not sure which one, but I don’t want to find out

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be working on an iPhone with iOS 13.
As a note, your above Git repo link is either private or on a different account.